# SQL: Access query unique meets multiple criterias

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2010, between

I have a table containing the columns ***studentID***, **course** and **start_date** where studentID is unique.
I want to write a query so that students that haven't gone to any courses with a start date within the year 2010 appears. My problem is that I seem to return all students that have gone to any course that isn't 2010 even though they have attended a course during 2010.

```
SELECT DISTINCT studentID
FROM attendant
WHERE Startdatum NOT BETWEEN #1/1/2010# AND #12/31/2010#
```

What I'm really asking is; Is there any way to not show a row if it contains a certain value? How?

Subquery of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT studentID FROM attendant
WHERE studentID NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT studentID FROM attendant
WHERE Startdatum BETWEEN #1/1/2010# AND #12/31/2010#)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is correct and I will use this. I tried with NOT IN but I tried to compare the start dates instead. This makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to answer this question is using the `having` clause:

```
SELECT studentID
FROM attendant
GROUP BY studentID
HAVING sum(iif(Startdatum BETWEEN #1/1/2010# AND #12/31/2010#, 1, 0)) = 0;
```

The `having` clause is counting the number of courses that each student took during the time frame.  If there are any, then the filter fails.

Comment: Did not know there existed a iif statement. This will indeed come in handy in my further studies. Thank you for the reply! This worked as accurate as well.

Comment: Zorro_blanco's answer is much more efficient.

Comment: @iDevlop . . . I don't see why it should be *much* more efficient.  Both require aggregating the data, so depending on the data, the combination with the `where` filter might make either version more efficient.